# Responsive header when window is smaller or on mobile - be creative

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am working on a website and I can't figure out how to make a responsive header. I have made a version where I am loading the header or the mobile-header which are 2 differents compenents but I fill that it's totally useless.

For now, I have the header below

[image]

With the associated react code :

```
import React  from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';
import SiteLogo from '../assets/images/village-logo.svg';
import './Header.css';
import LoginRegisterForm from './modal/loginRegisterForm';
import TextContents from '../assets/translations/TextContents';
import { Form, InputGroup } from 'react-bootstrap'
import SearchIcon from '../assets/images/search-icon.svg';
 
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import ArrowDropDownIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowDropDown';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Constant from '../config/Constant';

import UserDataUseCase from '../data/layer/UserDataUseCase';



class Header extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            anchorEl: null, 
            showLogin: false};
    }
    
    openLogin = () => {
        this.setState({showLogin: !this.state.showLogin});
    }

    handleClick = (event) => {
        this.setState({ anchorEl: event.currentTarget });
      };
    
    handleClose = () => {
        this.setState({ anchorEl: null })
      };

    handleLogout = () => {
        this.handleClose()
        sessionStorage.clear()
        window.open("/", "_self") //to open new page
    }

    render() {
        
        var authToken = sessionStorage.getItem(Constant.AUTH_TOKEN);

        var isLoggedIn

        if((authToken === null) || (authToken === 'undefined')){
            isLoggedIn = false;
        } else {
            isLoggedIn = true;
        }

        const menuLoginRegister = <Nav.Link 
            ref="LoginRegisterModal" eventKey={1} 
            href="#" 
            onClick={this.openLogin}
            bsPrefix="header-menu-item"
            >{TextContents.MenuLoginRegister}</Nav.Link>;

        const StyledProfileMenu = withStyles({
            paper: {
                border: '1px none',
                borderRadius: "21px",
                boxShadow: "0px 8px 18px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14)",
            },
            })((props) => (
            <Menu
                elevation={0}
                getContentAnchorEl={null}
                anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: 'bottom',
                horizontal: 'left',
                }}
                transformOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'center',
                }}
                {...props}
            />
            ));

        const StyledProfileMenuItem = withStyles((theme) => ({
            root: {
                margin: "2px 30px 1px 10px",
                fontFamily: "Source Sans Pro",
                fontSize: "16px",
                color: "#616161",
                fontStyle: "normal",
                '&:hover': {
                    backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
                    color: '#ff7255'},
        
                '&:focus': {
                    backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
                    color: '#ff7255'},
            },
            }))(MenuItem);    

        const menuProfile = 
                <div className="menu-profile">
                    <IconButton 
                        aria-controls="customized-menu" 
                        className="profile-icon-menu"
                        aria-haspopup="true" 
                        variant="contained"
                        color="secondary"
                        disableRipple="true"
                        disableFocusRipple="true"
                        onClick={this.handleClick}
                        style={{boxShadow: "0px 0px 0px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0)"}}>
                        <Avatar alt="Avatar" src={UserDataUseCase.getCurrentUserProfile().profilePic} /> 
                        <ArrowDropDownIcon style={{ color: "#ff7255" }}/>                    
                    </IconButton>
                    <StyledProfileMenu
                        id="simple-menu"
                        anchorEl={this.state.anchorEl}
                        keepMounted
                        open={Boolean(this.state.anchorEl)}
                        onClose={this.handleClose}
                        anchorOrigin={{
                            vertical: 'bottom',
                            horizontal: 'left',
                          }}
                          transformOrigin={{
                            vertical: 'top',
                            horizontal: 'center',
                          }}>
                            <p className="username-style"> {UserDataUseCase.getCurrentUserProfile().name} </p>
                            <Link href="/profile">
                                <StyledProfileMenuItem>{TextContents.MenuProfile}</StyledProfileMenuItem>
                            </Link>
                            <Link href="/buycredits">
                                <StyledProfileMenuItem>{TextContents.MenuCredits}</StyledProfileMenuItem>
                            </Link>
                            <Link href="/messages">
                                <StyledProfileMenuItem>{TextContents.MenuMessages}</StyledProfileMenuItem>
                            </Link>
                            <Link href="/settings">
                                <StyledProfileMenuItem>{TextContents.MenuSettings}</StyledProfileMenuItem>
                            </Link>
                            <StyledProfileMenuItem onClick={this.handleLogout}>Logout</StyledProfileMenuItem>
                        </StyledProfileMenu>
                    </div>;

        return (
            <div>
            <Navbar className="header-village" width="100" expand="lg">
                <Navbar.Brand href="/">
                    <img
                        src= { SiteLogo }
                        width="214"
                        height="28"
                        className="d-inline-block align-top"
                        alt="Village"
                    />
                </Navbar.Brand>
                <div className="search-menu-container">
                    <InputGroup className="header-search-container">
                        <InputGroup.Prepend>
                            <InputGroup.Text bsPrefix="header-search-prepend" id="inputGroupPrepend">
                            <img
                                src= { SearchIcon }
                                width="17"
                                height="17"
                                className="header-search-img"
                                alt="Village"
                            />
                            </InputGroup.Text>
                        </InputGroup.Prepend>
                        <Form.Control
                            type="text"
                            placeholder={TextContents.SearchPlaceHolder}
                            aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend"
                            bsPrefix="header-search-form"
                        />
                        </InputGroup>
                    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav"/>
                    <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                        <Nav className="menu-nav-header">
                        <Nav.Link bsPrefix="header-menu-item" href="/discover">{TextContents.MenuDiscover}</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link bsPrefix="header-menu-item" href="/create">{TextContents.MenuCreate}</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link bsPrefix="header-menu-item" href="/howitworks">{TextContents.MenuHiW}</Nav.Link>
                        {!isLoggedIn && menuLoginRegister}
                        {isLoggedIn && menuProfile}
                        </Nav>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                </div>

            </Navbar>
            <LoginRegisterForm displayPopUp={this.state.showLogin} onHide={() => this.setState({ showLogin: false })}/>
            </div>
            );
        }
}

export default Header;
```

and the associated css:

```
.header-village{
    width: 90%;
    height: 80px;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}


.header-search-container {
    width: 470px;
    min-width: 470px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-left: 60px;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}

.header-search-prepend {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-right: 0px none;
    background-color: #f4f7f8;
}

.header-search-img {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: auto;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    margin-top: 30%;

}

.header-search-form {
  width: 430px;
  height: 40px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  border-left: 0px none;     
  background-color: #f4f7f8;
  font-family: Source Sans Pro;
  text-align: left;
  color: #cecece;
}

.header-avatar-pic {
    width: 45px;
    height:45px;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.header-avatar-pic:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }

.header-menu-item {
    font-family: Fredoka One;
    font-size: 18px;
    color:#616161;
    margin-left:20px;
    min-width: 120px;
}


.header-menu-item:hover {
    color: #ff7255;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-bottom: 0px;
}

.search-menu-container{
    width:80%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0px;
}


.profile-icon {
    display: inline;
}


.header-divider {
    background-color: #ff7255; 

}

.menu-nav-header{
    margin-left: 50px;
    
}

.header-drop-down-name {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    color: #333333;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.nav-item{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    color: #616161;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.nav-item:hover{
    color: #ff7255;
}

.username-style {
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ff7255;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2px 11px 10px 11px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.menu-profile {
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.profile-icon-menu {
    border: none;
    background-color: red;
}

.profile-icon-menu:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }

  .login-hidden {
    display: none;
  }
```

so this is almost ok but I would like to have a dynamic/responsive behavior when the window is too small to display all of this and/or on mobile.

I would like to have the image starting from, on a desktop:

[image]

to (when screen, window is smaller to display all in one line, I will probable use also media to change some of the ?UI font size for mobile)

[image]

and then

[image]

I have a feeling that it should be so hard.

I have added a ling to https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-cache-q7t4g but it seems not working.

However, if it facilitate, you can just made an example using 3 text Part1, Part2 and Part 3. where Part1 is the logo, Part2 is the search and Part3 is the menu.

It will be easy to re-use this in my example.

Any idea ?

Regards

Comment: Any reason you don't use ``@media`` queries in CSS? More about them here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: @Dexterians So I use it in different place but I do not understand how I can achieve this using it. I am a newbie in react and css. So I use to have the `@media` query  but it wasn't working so I made a dirty hack by using media query in react to choose between 2 differents components. I would love, if you based on my example show me how to use it.

Comment: If you provide some HTML and CSS in a CodePen or JSFiddle we might be able to assist/show you how the ``@media`` queries in CSS work.

Comment: @Dexterians  I have added a link in the desc.

Comment: @Dexterians the sandbox seems not working properly but I think that a simple example using text instead of image, searcg and menu may be enoiugh to male me understand.

Comment: @Dexterians like a `part1`, `part2` and `part3` would be enough. I do not need to have all my componennts but just the mechanism

Comment: if you read the link I provided in my first comment along with this link; it should give you an idea how it works: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_responsive_header

Comment: Just remember, CSS flows downwards so the order in which you structure your CSS and Media Queries matters. If you scroll down to "Typical Device Breakpoints" in the first link I provided, you will see a typical ``@media`` query structure. Here's an example how it works: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=tryresponsive_mediaquery_breakpoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have wrote some css for you to fix the responsive issues, check the [code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-bassi-wx18j), see it full screen and then resize your browser, it will not break on any point,

all you need to do is use of media queries.

```
 @media (max-width: 991px) {
  .header-search-container {
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
  @media (max-width: 650px) {
  .header-search-container {
    order: 1;
    margin-top: 20px;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

The above CSS is just an example you to use media query, can change anything as per you need.